# CSS counter at specific number

Tags: css, counter

I want to use CSS counter in order to have an order list start at a specific number (7). I have successfully made it start at the right number but the problem is that the sub-list also started from that number.

//HTML

```
  <ol>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>
      <p>Fourth item - nested ordered list:</p>
      <ol>
        <li>
            <p>Fourth item - nested ordered list:</p>
            <ol>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
        <li>Second nested item</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ol>
```

//CSS

```
ol { counter-reset: item 6; list-style: none; }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

Expected:
I would want the list to start with the following order: 
7. First item 
8. 
9. 
10. 
  10.1 
    10.1.1 
    10.1.2 

Actual result: 
7. First item 
8. 
9. 
10. 
  10.7 
    10.7.7 
    10.7.8

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by simply defining the counter differently for the top level:

```
ol { counter-reset: item; list-style: none; }
body > ol { counter-reset: item 6; list-style: none; }
```

That would work for the simple example given, if the outermost `ol` is a direct child of body. If it isn’t, you can use a different parent element in the selector, or add a class to the outer `ol`, like

```
<ol class="outer">

ol { counter-reset: item; list-style: none; }
ol.outer { counter-reset: item 6; list-style: none; }
```